# how to fetch huge data from database and show it into drop-down list filter by typing input but should be chosen only from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, xampp

how to fetch huge data from database and show it into drop-down list. when user type anything fetch data accordingly by filter by typing input but data should be chosen or selected only from database it shouldn't pass as text input by user and then put that data of drop-down list option in that user table? Data is in Huge amount so it should show approx 10 or 15 data while filtering or typing in drop-down list. Working should be like when we chose our institution or living place in Facebook profile. 
In my code. it can select text input if it will not found in database so i want to get rid of that too.

```js
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>    
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#autoinput" ).autocomplete({
      source: 'searchuni.php'
    });
  });
  </script>
```

```css
.autocomplete {
  /*the container must be positioned relative:*/
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.autocomplete-items {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  z-index: 99;
  /*position the autocomplete items to be the same width as the container:*/
  top: 100%;
  left: 8%;
  right: 1%;
}
.autocomplete-items div {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4; 
}
.autocomplete-items div:hover {
  /*when hovering an item:*/
  background-color: #e9e9e9; 
}
.autocomplete-active {
  /*when navigating through the items using the arrow keys:*/
  background-color: DodgerBlue !important; 
  color: #ffffff; 
}
#autoinput{
    background-image: url(img/uniicon.png);
    background-position: 5px 2px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-indent:25px;
  }
```

```html
//html file element
<input id="autoinput" type="text" name="myUni" placeholder="University/School" required size="55"><span class="tooltiptext"><label name="uninamett">Choose your university by typing name.</label>
//searchuni php file
<?php
    //connect with the database
    $db = new mysqli($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);
    //get search term
    $searchTerm = $_GET['term'];
   //get matched data from skills table
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM university WHERE uniname LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY uniname ASC");
    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row['uniname'];
    }
    //return json data
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: what have you tried? where is your code?

Comment: No attempt from you?

Answer (score 0):

You can query the database with the user's input on that specific column using the like '%searchValue%' also you can filter the no of records using the limit 10